# DHCP assigns IP from Hilton hotel room ethernet port, but error at captive portal

Tags: ethernet, captive-portal

I've got my GL iNet + Tailscale (hosted back at home) setup at a Hilton and I managed to find a port on the Cisco router attached to the wall that works. I got assigned an IP and everything looks good on the GL iNet admin page side of things. However, when I go authenticate in the Hilton portal I get an error (299).

[image]

Note: I am able to successfully authenticate and use the Wi-Fi in repeater mode on my GL iNet router, but not using ethernet WAN due to this portal error. I have tried cloning MAC address, clearing DNS cache, rebooting, plugging/unplugging. Is it possible there's still some sort of ethernet security block happening here?

Comment: Are you asking how to bypass the internet security at a hotel?

Comment: @DubStep NO. I'm asking what is the reason for the error. Like is it possible for network security to block ethernet traffic, but DHCP from the router port still assigns an IP?

Comment: See if the router has passthru functionality that you connect to the hotel Ethernet, then connect the laptop to it and get it's DHCP, etc. from the machine you connect to the middle man router you are adding into the loop.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I think you're describing the situation I am already in. My GL-iNet router WAN port is connected to the hotel router on the wall and my laptop is connected to my GL-iNet router LAN port.

Comment: I probably don't fully understand the setup and configuration. If you have access to Wireshark and know what to look for (or can learn it) with it then you could run a trace on the laptop direct connect (when it works), then run another trace from the connected router from the laptop (when it does not work). Then you may see the differences at the network packets level potentially.